# Proving continuity when partial derivatives are bounded on open set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

Below is the problem that I described in my title and a proof for it below.   Before looking at this solution I was trying to prove it by showing that the partials are continuous, which would imply that $f$ is differentiable and hence continuous.  I had trouble using the bounded property to show that $|\partial_xf(x,y)-\partial_xf(a,b)| \leq |(x,y)-(a,b)|$.  Is it possible to prove this inequality using the bounded property? and is it at all possible to prove differentiability of $f$ as the method of proving continuity? I would also be interested to see other proofs of the coninuity of $f$ such as by the way of the open set condition, or using sequential convergence.

---

[image]

**Solution**

[image]

Comment: The question gave you a big clue that it's not possible to prove continuity by proving differentiability when it stated that the previous exercise (whatever it is) gives an example of a function satisfying the given conditions but **which is not differentiable.** The given solution (whose intuition is to break up a path from point near $x_0$ into one-variable paths, and use the partial derivatives to show that the function acts continuously along each of the one-variable paths) is what I would consider the "obviously correct" approach. That is uses the MVT is optional, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and for the explanation!

Comment: @davidlowryduda Also, maybe I'm missing something obvious, but in their proof, why does continuity follow from showing that $|f(a+h)-f(a)|\leq C(|h_1|+|h_2|)$?  We want to show it's less than $|h|$ and I know that $|h_1|+|h_2|\geq |h|$ but not sure how to proceed.  Or does continuity follow from the fact that we've proven that $f$ is locally differentiable by noticing that $\dfrac{|f(a+h)-f(a)|}{|h_1|+|h_2|}\leq C$?

Comment: To add one additional inequality, $\lvert f(a+h) - f(a) \rvert \leq C (\lvert h_1 \rvert + \lvert h_2 \rvert) \leq C( \lvert h \rvert + \lvert h \rvert) \leq 2 C \lvert h \rvert$. So it's just with (at worst) twice the constant as comes from the derivative bound.

Comment: I still don't see how $f(a+h)-f(a) \leq 2C|h|$ implies that $f(a+h)-f(a)\leq |h|$, if that's what your showing.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused regarding the definition of continuity. For example, the function $g(x) = 3x$ (in dimension $1$) doesn't satisfy $\lvert g(x+h) - g(x) \rvert \leq \lvert h \rvert$. But it does satisfy $\lvert g(x+h) - g(x)\rvert \leq 3 \lvert h \rvert$, and is of course continuous.