# Why continuity follows for $|f(a+h)-f(a)| \leq k|h|$, where $k$ is a scalar constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

The other day I asked a question related to the problem below, then I realized that I wasn't sure how the inequality $|f(a+h)-f(a)| \leq C(|h_1|+|h_2)|$--very last line of their proof--implied continuity of $f$.  Someone then commented that we can extend the inequality by writing $\lvert f(a+h) - f(a) \rvert \leq C (\lvert h_1 \rvert + \lvert h_2 \rvert) \leq C( \lvert h \rvert + \lvert h \rvert) \leq 2 C \lvert h \rvert$ but I still didn't see how continuity followed

My thinking was to think in terms of the delta-epsillon definition but then I was stuck trying to show that $|f(a+h)-f(a)| \leq |h|$, which a commenter pointed out that it failed in some cases, such as the case of $f(x)=3x$.

**My Question**

Could you explain why this inequality in their last line implies continuity and why scalar constants on $|h|$ still allow for continuity to follow?

Thanks, and here's the link to where I asked the other question.  In the comments you'll see where we discuss continuity.

[Proving continuity when partial derivatives are bounded on open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849011/proving-continuity-when-partial-derivatives-are-bounded-on-open-set)

---

[image]

**Solution**

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then for $\|h\| < \min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{ C\sqrt2}, r\right\}$ we have

$$|f(a+h) - f(a)| \le C(|h_1| + |h_2|) \stackrel{CSB}{\le} C\sqrt{2}\sqrt{|h_1|^2+|h_2|^2} = C\sqrt2 \|h\| < \varepsilon$$

Comment: What does CSB stand for above $\leq$?

Comment: @johnfowles [Cauchy-Schwarz-Bunyakovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). You can also use $|h_1| + |h_2| \le 2\|h\|$ if you wish.

Comment: If I use the case $|h_1| + |h_2| \le 2\|h\|$ then I should pick my $\delta = \text{ min}{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2c},r}$?

Comment: @johnfowles Pick $\delta = \min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{ 2C}, r\right\}$, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the proof says that for any $r>0$ and $\lvert\textbf{h}\rvert < r$ the difference $\lvert f(a+h)-f(a) \rvert$ is less than $C(|h_1|+|h_2|)$.

Now we know, that we can make $r$ as small as we want. Since this holds for any $r>0$ (that is small enough), the only possible thing this can me is that $|f(a+h)-f(a)| \to 0$ as $r \to 0$.

That is for any small distance $r>0$, the difference between function values that are less than $r$ distant from $a$ and $f(a)$ is lesser than  $C(|h_1|+|h_2|)$. This should intuitively represent the concept of continuity.

To convert this idea into $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof, you just make your $\varepsilon:=C(|h_1|+|h_2|)$ and find $r$ (as your $\delta$) accordingly.